# Can you say "in there"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, adverbs

I was reading Harry Potter and I had a question.

> After lunch they went to the reptile house. It was cool and dark **in there**, with lit windows along the walls.

I'm confused because I learned that usually you can't use an adverb with prepositions. Does it sound more natural to you than saying "It was cool and dark there."? And what do you find the difference between "in there" and "there", concerning this sentence?

Comment: A deceptively tricky question—well done.

Comment: I hadn't thought of this example before, but I think part of the answer has to be that when you learn a language, one thing you need to learn is how words are conventionally used in combinations with other words.

Comment: It is to my ear (native English speaker) very natural.  Now I am trying to think of when I would use just 'there" and when I would use "in there".  With a reptile house or a cave, or a tunnel or anyplace that I am emphasizing is enclosed, I'd probably use "in there."  And if I were inside my house and heard a strange noise outside, I might say: "What made that noise out there?"

Comment: I find it curious that "there" is not defined, in at least some senses, as a pronoun, as one can very often substitute "it" with little change in meaning and no change in sentence structure.  But as to using an adverb with a preposition, [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/there) gives the example of *I'm not going in there—it's freezing*, and claims that the word is an adverb in that sense.

Comment: @Auraucaria "There" is not so much an adverb (or preposition) here as it is a pronoun like "this" or "that". The antecedent is "The reptile house".

Comment: An interesting tool for this kind of question is Google's Book Ngram Viewer.  You can go in there and find out which words are are likely to precede or follow a given word sequence.  For example, what is the most common word that precedes "in there", the answer is "go", as in "go in there."  You do the query by placing an asterisk as a place holder for the missing word, for example "* in there" - here's a link to that query: http://goo.gl/Uql5hA

Comment: Thank you all for answering my question. I'm surprised because I didn't expect I would get so many reactions. This is the first time I use this site, so I think this is a kind of beginner's luck. 
It wasn't easy for an intermediate English learner to read all your comments and answers, but it was worth spending two hours. Especially I liked Araucaria's tests to judge whether this word is adverb or preposition, and the idea of seeing "there" as a preposition phrase. 
All the information that you have given to me cannnot be found in my English-Japanese dictionaries. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10):

### **Short answer**

Yes, you can.

Modern grammars such as the Oxford Modern English Grammar show *there* to be a preposition, not an adverb. The preposition *in* cannot take adverbs or adverb phrases as Complements. It *can* take other preposition phrases as Complements. For this reason there is no problem using the word *there* after the preposition *in*.

When we use *there* with a stative verb, it has a general meaning of *at that place*. If you want to say something like *in and at that place*, you can say *in there*.

---

### **Full answer**

In modern grammars such as *Oxford Modern English Grammar* (2011) or *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (2002), prepositions are a class of word like verbs, nouns, adjectives and so forth which have specific properties. Although taking noun phrases as Complements is a common feature of typical prepositions, this is not a necessary feature of this class of word. So many prepositions like the word *out* often occur without a following noun phrase:

- Bertha walked out.

This is similar to how, although many verbs take noun phrases as Direct Objects,  this is not a mandatory feature of verbs. These developments regarding prepositions, have not filtered into dictionaries yet. [This is likely to take many decades](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-word-parts). Traditional grammars and modern dictionaries take words like *out* in the sentence above to be an adverb because it doesn't have a following noun phrase.

According to linguists such as Jespersen and Emonds and modern grammars such as CamGEL and OMEG, the word *there* is a preposition (some linguists think of it as a pro-preposition). It passes every test for preposition-hood and none of the tests for being an adverb.

It can appear as a  Locative Complement of the verb *BE*:

- She is **inside the building.**
- She is **there**.
- *She is **locally**. (adverb as LC, ungrammatical)

It can be modified by the specialised adverb *right*, which can premodify many preposition phrases, but cannot premodify adverbs in standard English:

- It is **right at the top**.
- It is **right there**.
- *It is **right locally**. (*right* modifying adverb, ungrammatical)

It can be premodified by the specialised adverb *straight*, which can premodify many preposition phrases, but cannot modify adverbs in standard English:

- Go **straight past the traffic lights**.
- Go **straight there**.
- *Go **straight directly**. (*right* modifying adverb, ungrammatical)

Preposition phrases can freely postmodify nouns, adverbs usually cannot:

- that dog **in the window**
- that dog **there**
- that dog **cutely** (*adverb* postmodifying noun, ungrammatical)

We can usually use the adverb *very* to modify adverbs. We can't use it to modify prepositions or preposition phrases such as *there*:

- *She lives **very beyond the border**. (*very* + preposition, ungrammatical)
- *She lives **very there**. (*very* + preposition, ungrammatical)
- She lives **very locally**.

All of this information shows that *there* is a preposition and not an adverb.

**The Original Poster's question**

The original Poster says that prepositions cannot usually take adverbs as Complements. This is a good rule of thumb! But it might be better to think about prepositions in the same way we think about verbs. Some verbs don't take Complements. Some verbs only take noun phrases as Complements. Other verbs cannot take noun phrases as Complements, but only take preposition phrases and so forth.

The preposition *until* can take adverb phrases as Complements:

- until recently

However, the preposition *in* cannot:

- *in locally (*in* plus adverb, ungrammatical)

However, the preposition *in* can, of course, take preposition phrases as Complements:

- in from the cold

For this reason we can use *there* as a Complement of the preposition *in*:

- in there

The word *there* means something like *at that place* when it is used with stative verbs. If you want to say something like *at that place and in that place*, you can just say *in there*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48752/discussion-on-answer-by-araucaria-can-you-say-in-there).

Answer (score 2):

The word [*there*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/there) could be used as either an *adverb* which doesn't require a preposition and a noun which means

> that place / that point.

(You need to note some other dictionaries classify it as a pronoun)

The sentence could be rephrased to

> It was cool and dark in that place (the reptile house).

You should note that *there* could be used with many prepositions such as 'up there', 'down there', 'out there', etc. The same applies to the word *here*.

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48753/discussion-on-answer-by-rathony-can-you-say-in-there).

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the nonsense about "there" being an adverb or a pronoun, read the original text:

> After lunch they went to the reptile house. It was cool and dark in
>   there, with lit windows along the walls.

At the end of the first sentence "they" are "at" the reptile house.  There is no indication that they have entered it.  If the text continued "It was cool and dark there", without "in", the reader would be left wondering if it was cool and dark *outside* the reptile house.

"In" is necessary to convey the full meaning of the text.