# What is the part of speech is "on" in the phrase "A few miles further on"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, adverbs, parts-of-speech

There is an example sentence:

> We found a secluded beach a few miles further on.

In this sentence, I referred to the dictionary and found that the part of speech of *further* is an adverb. However *on* is given [both as a preposition and an adverb](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on), with very many definitions.

In addition, [this post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-words-part/6635#6635) suggests that we shouldn't rely on dictionaries too much for grammatical information anyway.

The answers and comments below give responses from trusted users which give opposing analyses—some indicating *on* is an adverb here and some saying it is a preposition.

So I can't figure out that what the part of speech of *on* is. Secondly what is the meaning of *on* in this sentence?

Comment: Do the test. Try replacing it with a different word of which you now the part of speech for certain. See if it works. Can you replace "further on" with a noun? With a verb? an adjective? an adverb? Exactly one of these things will work. All other things will not work at all. That means that the syntax of the sentence only allows one part of speech in that position, and so that's the part of speech that "further on" is as well.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Well you can replace it with preposition phrases. But you can't replace it with bona fide adverbs, of course: "a few miles further far" is ungrammatical. So is "a few miles further distantly" and "a few miles further long". But "a few miles further into the forest" seems fine. So does "a few miles further down the road". (Oh, and "a few miles further in" and "a few miles further down"). Doesn't look like Nadia's talking ****** after all, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that 'on' is not a preposition, because there is no noun or noun phrase that could go with it. It must be an adverb.
Cambridge Dictionary gives you this:

> **on**, *adverb* (MOVING FORWARD), continuing forward in time or space:
>   *They never spoke to each other from that day on* (= after that day).

Both in your example and in that provided by Cambridge Dictionary, the sentences would mean the same thing and be correct as well. The 'on' doesn't so much mean something definite as it adds a certain emphasis to the adverb/adverbial phrase *further/from that day* that it modifies, underlining an aspect of progression.

Comment: I refer to Oxford Dictionary, and I am not a native English speaker. And *on* can be used as an adverb and preposition.

Comment: "*A preposition or postposition typically combines with a noun or pronoun, or more generally a noun phrase, this being called its complement, or sometimes object.*" (Wikipedia, Preposition and Postposition)

Comment: Never use dictionaries for parts of speech. It's not what they're there for.

Comment: Interesting _opinion_, Araucaria. Maybe you should also point out what you don't like about my answer contentwise, because your claim sounds exaggerated. And you don't provide another source either.

Comment: For the reasons that linguists don't use dictionaries for parts of speech [see here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-words-part/6635#6635). For alternative analyses of intransitive prepositions see the preposition chapter [here, in ASIEG, by Huddleston & Pullum 2005](https://www.slideshare.net/MrMinhajahmed/a-students-introduction-to-english-grammar). It starts on p.126. Alternatively you could look in [Oxford Modern English Grammar](https://www.amazon.com/Oxford-Modern-English-Grammar-Aarts/dp/0199533199)

Answer (score 5):

*Further on* is a compound adverb. It makes no sense to ask what part of speech *on* is in this context.

*Collins Cobuild English Grammar* (p303) has other examples in the section on *adverbs of position*:

> 'Deep down', 'far away', 'high up', and 'low down' are often used
>   instead of adverbs on their own.
>
> - The window was high up, miles above the rocks.
> - Sita scraped a shallow cavity, low down in the wall.
>
> 'Far' and 'far way' are often qualified by a prepositional phrase
>   beginning with 'from'.

Google has numerous examples of the adverb '*further on*' followed by a prepositional phrase beginning with *from*. For example:

- [further on from the hotel](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22further%20on%20from%20the%20hotel%22&oq=%22further%20on%20from%20the%20hotel%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.2303j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Lexemes, lexemes, lexemes.

Comment: Hi Shoe. I don't think it makes sense to view *further on* as a compound word here. [*A few miles on*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1GGGE_en-gbGB472GB472&biw=1517&bih=698&q=%22a+few+miles+on+we%22&oq=%22a+few+miles+on+we%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i30k1.14607.14968.0.15198.3.3.0.0.0.0.99.267.3.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.265...0i22i30k1j0i8i7i30k1.tzp52NMpsa8) shows that *on* works fine on its own. So with *further on*, it seems very reasonable to view *further* as a modifier of the word *on*. Another thing to think about is that we could easily stick a complement onto the word on here...

Comment: ... *A few miles further on from where they had been*. In this case *on* would be viewed as a preposition. There is at least some case to be made that *on* is a preposition as opposed to an adverb. Indeed, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* analyse instances of such words as intransitive uses of prepositions.

Comment: @Araucaria. Thanks for the tip about intransitive prepositions. Sounds like an oxymoron to me, but I look forward to reading what Huddlestone and Pullum have to say. So do I understand you to claim that _further on from the hotel_ should be parsed: (adverb) _further_ .. (prepositional phrase) _on from the hotel_, with _on from_ being a compound preposition similar to _in front of_ or _out of_?

Comment: You can read their analysis of preposition starting on [page 127 of ASIEG, here](https://www.slideshare.net/MrMinhajahmed/a-students-introduction-to-english-grammar). H&P (and many others) view prepositions as aclass of word which like verb, nouns or adjectives can take a wide range of complements. So they would take *further* as an adverb modifying the PP *on from the hotel*, as you say. However, they would regard that PP as consisting of a head preposition *on*  taking a second PP *from the hotel* as its complement. :)

Comment: Fancy giving this question a reopen vote?

Comment: @Araucaria, Thanks. The frequent questions on this site asking for the classification of words are of theoretical interest to me, but I often ask myself what the askers are going to do with the (often conflicting, as in this case) answers they are given - beyond maybe gaining an appreciation that linguistics is not mathematics!.

Comment: @Araucaria. Voted as requested - with the hope that you will provide your own answer!

Comment: @Shoe Well, they could be given "traditionally it would be regarded as an A but modern grammars usually analyse it as a P" kind of answer. But I think that when askers query parts of speech they often have a theoretical interest themselves. But knowing that *on* is a prep can be of practical help to Ss. For example, unlike most adverbs preps can't  be modified by *very*: "Very on from the hotel" won't work for example :)

Comment: @Shoe [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358947/can-you-say-in-there) might be helpful in showing why this kind of info can be useful for students (I hope!)

Answer (score 1):

The word "on" by itself is a preposition. " Further" is an adverb. Together, "further" and "on" make a prepositional phrase which I think works as an adjective here since it refurs to "miles".

Comment: Ok, thank you. And there are two different opinions.

Comment: −1 I think you are confused what a prepositional phrase is. A prepositional phrase is not simply any phrase that has a preposition somewhere. Much rather, a prepositional phrase begins with a preposition that modifies the head of the phrase, the preposition's object, typically a noun phrase. An example of a prepositional phrase is "on the table", or "on Saturdays". "I sit on a chair" is not a prepositional phrase. "On and on" is not a preposition phrase. "Further on" is not a prepositional phrase. There is no head that the *on* is modifiying. The "on" itself *is* the head. It modifies nothing.

Comment: @RegDwigнt That idea of what a preposition is, is a little bit outdated now. It's now a hundred years since [Otto Jespersen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Jespersen) first pointed out that that view of prepositions is illogical. Since the seventies this has been a mainstream view in linguistics, and is the standard view of modern grammars such as *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* and *Oxford Modern English Grammar*. All in all, your comments to Nadia are a bit OTT, and, well, just rather misplaced. Many modern linguists would say that they are laughably wrong.

Comment: @RegDwigнt At the very least you should understand that the preposition is the head of the phrase (erm, that's why it's called a preposition phrase). The preposition isn't modifying the rest of the phrase. The rest of the phrase (if there is one) is its complement. In modern grammar (the kind they teach on syntax courses at universities and use in published research), prepositions, like verbs and other categories of word can take different types of complements (noun phrases, adjective phrases, adverb phrases, finite clauses, gerund-participle clauses, other preposition phrases), or ...

Comment: @RegDwigнt ... they may take none at all. In the same way that *water* in *Water is good for you* can be regarded as a noun phrase, and *smoke* can be regarded as a verb phrase in *I smoke*, the preposition *out* can be regarded as a preposition phrase in *I went out*. To the extent that *works as an adjective*  is misleading, it is only as misleading as the thousands of people who regularly say the same thing on this site when what they really mean is *modifier of a noun*. (although *a few miles* is actually modifying *further* and that whole adverb phrase is modifying *on*, of course)

Comment: @RegDwigнt Maybe you'd like to take a look at what H&P, for example, say about prepositions. That section starts on [page 127 here](https://www.slideshare.net/MrMinhajahmed/a-students-introduction-to-english-grammar).