# Can a preposition be before an adverb?

Tags: nouns, adverbs, pronouns, parts-of-speech

Ok, [this site](http://eslus.com/LESSONS/GRAMMAR/POS/pos7.htm) says

> The preposition is **almost always before the noun or pronoun** and that
>   is why it is called a preposition

Now, [this oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/here_1?q=here) says

> **here** (adverb)
>
> used **after a verb or preposition** to mean ‘in, at or to this
>   position or place’
>
> I live here.
>
> Put the box here.
>
> Let's get out of here.
>
> Come over here.

So, the dictionary says "***here*** is an adverb & we can put a preposition before ***here***"

Eg: *I am in here*

I would say the dictionary is not correct, "**here**" in "**in here**" is a pronoun or noun. But I am not sure.

The same thing happened to "**there**".

Eg: *he is in there; he is up there*

**Can a preposition be before an adverb?**

Comment: For the second question, see **Can you say “in there”?** https://english.stackexchange.com/q/358947/14666

Comment: Modern grammar treats "here" as a preposition: "in/to this place". [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/here)

Comment: @BillJ, I don't understand why you said that. A preposition can not stand alone. It must be followed by a noun "He is outside the kitchen" or else it will be an adverb "He is outside"

Comment: @Kris, I read the link, I would say sometimes "there/ here" is an adverb, sometimes it is a pronoun. "Go there (there: adv)", "Go in there (there: pronoun)", "right there (there is an adv and is modified by another adverb 'right')"

Answer (score -1):

*Here* is an adverb modifying *live* in "I live here."

We say "I live in Texas." not "*I live Texas." *Texas* is a noun; with the preposition, *in Texas* is an adverbial phrase.

Comment: but what about prep "in" in "I am in here"?

Comment: That's a second question!

Comment: Texas is not a proper noun? A prepositional phrase, the entire thing is an adverbial phrase.